# Can 2 React-Native applications communicate with each other?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am working on a project where `App A` has to be running all the time. Meaning that in each crash or reboot of the initial device, the application has to be restarted. I want to do this using another application, `App B`, which will constantly check the version (or something else) of `App A`. Is this possible and if so, what is the best method?

I have tried using `AppState` && `Linking` but this gave performance issues. I have tried writing a script in the `Android` folder that automatically boots the application and thankfully this works.

So my question is, is it possible for `App B` to check the status of `App A` and if no response, start `App A`?